# Is the obvious function $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(W)\to\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(S)}(S\otimes W)$ bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $S$ and $W$ be complex and finite-dimensional vector spaces. In the following we consider the obvious action of $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(S)$ on $S$ and $S\otimes W$. Since
$$\forall A\in\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(W):1\otimes A\in\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(S)}(S\otimes W)$$
we can ask whether the function
\begin{align}
\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(W)&\to\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(S)}(S\otimes W)\\
A&\mapsto 1\otimes A
\end{align}
is bijective. Injectivity should be clear, so the main issue should be surjectivity.

Motivation: AFAIU this is claimed without proof in proposition 3.27 of [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628).

Related: [Spinor representation and Clifford modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541776/572841)

Comment: Did you try a dimension argument?

Comment: @MaximilianSimon You mean showing that $V:=\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(W)$ and $W:=\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(S)}(S\otimes W)$ viewed as $\mathbb C$-vector spaces have the same dimension and then using that an injective function $f\in L_{\mathbb C}(V,W)$ is automatically surjective as well?

Comment: Yes, I think that should work.

Comment: @MaximilianSimon My naive approach would be to assume a basis $A=(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$ of $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(W)$ and trying to show that $B=(1\otimes A_1,\ldots,1\otimes A_n)$ is a basis of $\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(S)}(S\otimes W)$ - but showing that $B$ spans the entire space boils down to the initial problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to show that if $T=\sum_iA_i\otimes B_i$ is in $\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(S)}(S\otimes W)$, then $\forall i:A_i=1$ (maybe by contradiction)?