# Definition of the twisting space of a Clifford module

Tags: clifford-algebras

Let $V$ be an even-dimensional euclidean vector space, $S$ the spinor module and $E$ a module of the Clifford algebra $C(V)$. Then
$$W=\mathrm{Hom}_{C(V)}(S,E)$$
is called the twisting space of $E$. Now here is the issue:

In the book [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) the elements of $W$ are defined to super-commute with the Clifford action$^1$, but I think that they should be defined to commute with Clifford action:

The function $T\in L(S\otimes W,E)$ defined by
$$T(s\otimes w)=w(s)$$
is even and hence it super-commutes with the Clifford action if and only if it commutes with the Clifford action. And this is the case if and only if all elements of $W$ commute with the Clifford action:

Fix $x\in C(V)$, $s\in S$ and $w\in W$, then
$$(T\circ c_{S\otimes W}(x))(s\otimes w)=T(c_S(x)\otimes 1(s\otimes w))=T(c_S(x)(s)\otimes w)=(w\circ c_S(x))(s)$$and$$(c_E(x)\circ T)(s\otimes w)=(c_E(x)\circ w)(s)$$and hence $T\circ c_{S\otimes W}(x)=c_E(x)\circ T$ if and only if $\forall w\in W:w\circ c_S(x)=c_E(x)\circ w$.

---

$^1$ To be precise, the elements of $\mathrm{End}_{C(V)}(E)$ are explicitly defined to super-commute with the Clifford action and the exact definition $\mathrm{Hom}_{C(V)}(S,E)$ is not included in the book.

Comment: This is what I've also confused. I also agree with your opinion. It does NOT supercommute at all

Comment: I think the way to tackle this is considering W have a trivial grading.. but I;m not sure every thing is okay

Comment: @ChoMedit "I think the way to tackle this is considering W have a trivial grading" - Can you elaborate?  I think that $T$ is even w.r.t. the grading discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450387/281518).

Comment: What I'd thought is that let the grading of elements in $W$ be one. However, I think this idea is not that good enough, since we require $W$ be a supergraded.

Comment: @ChoMedit Note that proposition $3.27$ says that $E$ is isomorphic to $S\otimes W$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded complex $C(V)$-module, so $T\in\mathrm{Hom}_{C(V)}(S\otimes W,E)$ should be even and we achieve that by considering the before-mentioned grading on $W$ and the tensor-product grading on $S\otimes W$.

Comment: Yes, so we don't need any presumed(I mean, not from the definition) grading on $W$. I think your story and conclusion in the post is right.

Comment: @ChoMedit Thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: I come back because I found it very strange.. In the proof of Gauss-Bonnet-Chern by using ASindex, it uses a supercommuting elements.. $W$ should be a  set of supercommuting elements. It seems really critical, I couldn't catch what's right.

Comment: Perhaps, we need to choose another Clifford action on $W \otimes S$ to make everything right.

Comment: @ChoMedit Can you tell me the page number?

Comment: It's page 148. Actually there appears two grading structures, but I'm not sure what's what.

Comment: @ChoMedit I don't see a contradiction: Each grading on $E$ induces a grading on $W=\mathrm{Hom}_{C(V)}(S,E)$. Since we consider two different gradings on $E$, it is not surprising that we obtain two different gradings on $W$.

Comment: @ChoMedit If we consider the grading defined by the chirality operator, then $W$ is purely even, because the elements of $W$ commute with $C(V)$ and hence in particular with the grading (the chirality operator).

Comment: Yeah.. the grading is not a problem. The problem seems due to the definition of $W$.

Comment: How about moving this discussion to the chat? I think there is a subtle point around $W$ and archiving those points are useful for future.

Comment: @ChoMedit Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150003/discussion-between-filippo-and-chomedit).

Comment: @ChoMedit May I raise your attention to a related issue? I think that in the definition of Clifford super-connections the square brackets should be interpreted as a commutators, not super-commutators. I have explained my reasoning [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/458870/281518). I would like to hear your opinion.

Comment: I am also very confused with this. Assume one defined $\text{Hom}_{C(V)}(S, E)$ to be the space of complex linear maps $f: S\to E$ such that $f(c(v)x)=c(v)f(x)$ for any $x\in S$, then by Schur's lemma one would conclude $\text{Hom}_{C(V)}(S, S)={\mathbb C}$ and in general $\text{Hom}_{C(V)}(S, E)={\mathbb C}^d$, and there seems to have no clear way to define a bi-grade on $W=\text{Hom}_{C(V)}(S, E)$. I have no idea if this is the way it should be.

Comment: If take the above interpretation, on the left of (3.10) it is just the ordinary trace, on the right it is a block-diagonal matrix with each block a multiple of $\Gamma$, hence taking supertrace in this case is just like taking ordinary trace with no $\Gamma$, so (3.10) can be "proved", but this looks shaky to me (why need the "super" machinery?).

Comment: @Yuval I think that $\mathrm{Hom}_{C(V)\otimes\mathbb{C}}(S,E)$ inherits a grading from $L_{\mathbb C}(S,E)$, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456189/281518). Does this resolve the issue or do you still see a contradiction?

Comment: @Yuval Concerning (3.10): Let $T\in\mathrm{Hom}_{C(V)\otimes\mathbb{C}}(S\otimes W,E)$ be the isomorphism from my answer. Note that the isomorphism of complex algebras$$\mathrm{End}(W)\to\mathrm{End}_{C(V)\otimes\mathbb{C}}(E)$$maps $F$ to $T(1\otimes F) T^{-1}$, so (3.10) should really be read as$$2^{n/2}\mathrm{Str}_W(F)=\mathrm{Str}_E(c_E(\Gamma)T(1\otimes F) T^{-1}).$$ But this is easy since $$2^{n/2}=\mathrm{Str}_S(c_S(\Gamma))$$where $\Gamma\in C(V)\otimes \mathbb{C}$ is the chirality operator and hence

Comment: $$2^{n/2}\mathrm{Str}_W(F)=\mathrm{Str}_{S\otimes W}(c_S(\Gamma)\otimes F)=\mathrm{Str}_E(T(c_S(\Gamma)\otimes 1)(1\otimes F)T^{-1})=\mathrm{Str}_E(c_E(\Gamma)T(1\otimes F)T^{-1})$$